# Logging while testing through Gradle

Tags: java, scala, logging, gradle

While testing, Gradle appears to redirect stdout/stderr to `project_dir/build/reports/tests/index.html`. Is there a way to avoid this redirection, and get things printed to the console instead?

Additional information:

- It's a Scala 2.9.1 project.
- I am using [slf4s](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s) for logging.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
apply plugin : 'java'

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

This requires a current gradle version. I am assuming that the Scala tests are run under the Java test task.

Comment: Whoops on testing it looks like it doesn't, this produces output for me though:

http://pastebin.com/PX8e1EKv

edit: amend the println to a print as I think the event captures the newline

Comment: thanks. I'll try that too. I have some log statements in source files too. How do I make them print to console?

Comment: It depends on the logging implementation. slf4s might be defaulting to a NOP logger and discarding your log statement. Do you have a logger implementation jar on the test classpath? If slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar is present it will log INFO and above to STDERR. If that isn't enough I would add a logback jar and set up a logback-test.xml to append logs to the console.

Comment: Worked for me w/ Spring/JUnit

Comment: It "doesn't work" possibly because the test task is considered up to date and doesn't run hence you see no output. You can either do `$ gradle clean test` or use `outputs.upToDateWhen {false}` inside the `testLogging` block (`test { testLogging { outputs...`). For details see the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html#upToDateWhen-groovy.lang.Closure-).

Comment: @missingfaktor this works for sysouts and log.error but not for log.info()

Comment: It works on Terminal but my IntelliJ doesn't show the logs during Graddle tasks running.

Answer (score 42):

I am using also (`testLogging.exceptionFormat = 'full'`):

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    testLogging.exceptionFormat = 'full'
}
```

Which is good to see more from stacktrace

Comment: The `exceptionFormat` setting worked for me, `showStandardStreams` had no effect!

Answer (score 30):

## For Android Gradle Files

If you are inside an android gradle file (if `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` is at the top of your build.gradle file)

Then paste this into build.gradle

```
// Test Logging
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        events "standardOut", "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

## For Regular Gradle Files

Paste this into build.gradle

```
// Test Logging
test {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

As **[@roby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357286/4484016)** answered:

adding the following code to your `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin : 'java'

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

***Important!***

You need to run gradle test or build with added `clean` command.

```
./gradlew clean test

or

./gradlew clean build
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Could you explain why "clean" would be needed?

Comment: @MichaelKanis because you've been changed the gradle configuration..as far as I know, the gradle configuration is cached.

Comment: @nmfzone that means you need to run clean test once to update the cache. But in my scenario, I need to run clean command every time just to show the test result on console. Even though no change to gradle config is made on following runs.

Comment: @WeishiZeng are you sure that tests simply are not running because their inputs have not changed?  If you have some test input other than java source files, you should register them as Task.inputs, so gradle can know when you need to rerun tests or not.

Answer (score 19):

Just to add, the:

```
showStandardStreams = true
```

is a [shorthand](https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer:showStandardStreams) for:

```
events = ["standard_out", "standard_error"]
```

It is important to keep this in mind when mixing both entries as the following:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
        events = ["passed", "failed", "skipped"]
    }
}
```

will result in **no stdout** whereas the reverse order:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        events = ["passed", "failed", "skipped"]
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

will add the stdout entries to the list, so **stdout will work**.

See [the source](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v4.5.1/subprojects/testing-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/logging/DefaultTestLogging.java) for details.

Comment: When `showStandardStreams` comes second in the ordering, just to double check, do the standard streams get _appended_ to the events list? It seems like it, but just double checking.

Answer (score 15):

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

and

```
test {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

also works.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Kotlin DSL with `build.gradle.kts` the syntax is a bit different.

Make sure you have the junit in your dependencies:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
}
```

Then you need to add to your test task:

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
        exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        events("skipped", "failed")
    }
}
```

Then you can adjust the settings based on your need.

Answer (score 9):

For Android Gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425815/413127

For Android Gradle KTS (Kotlin):

```
// Test Logging
tasks.withType<Test> {
    testLogging {
        events("standardOut", "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
./gradlew --info clean build test
```

Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.

Comment: `--info` and `--debug` will display too many Gradle logs, most of time we do not need them

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working with Java and Spring-boot-starter-test.

I had the same issue and the problem was that I did not have any test engine.

So I add one to the dependencies of the build.gradle and it has work.

> testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api',
>   version: dependencyVersion.junit5
>       testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: dependencyVersion.junit5

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @joshuakcockrell and @Blundell solutions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425815/2385906) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69930299/2385906)), when dealing with a multi-module android app the following can be used (root `build.gradle`)

```
// Call from root build.gradle
setupTestLogging()

fun Project.setupTestLogging() {
    for (sub in subprojects) {
        sub.tasks.withType<Test> {
            testLogging {
                exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(note that while `exceptionFormat` alone should be enough to get the wanted outcome, the `events("standardOut" ...)` mentioned above can be specified in the same way)