# Jenkins does not show log4j logs

Tags: java, jenkins, logging, junit, log4j

my problem is that I can not see the JUnit log4j logs of my integration tests, when I run them on jenkins.

When I start them from my local eclipse everything works fine. I tried Java Utils Logging before that worked fine as well.

I tried lots of log4j.properties settings. The current one looks as follows:

```
# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE
#log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

# Set the enterprise logger priority to FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.enterprise=FATAL
log4j.logger.de.hunsicker.jalopy.io=FATAL
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=FATAL

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %m%n

# LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=axis2.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

What am I doing wrong? The `log4j.properties` file is placed in `/src/main/resources`. As there is no `No log4j appenders`-warning in the log, I assume that it is in the classpath and consumed.

Comment: Have you added the log recorder in jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in [Logging while testing through Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356543/logging-while-testing-through-gradle)

The problem was in the gradle settings:

```
testLogging {
    events 'passed', 'failed', 'standardError'
    showStandardStreams = true
}
```