# How do I print to the stdout when a gradle build runs?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, stdout

Gradle has a separate logging from java (eg. slf4j), but I am wondering if I can get my java code (within a unit test) to print out messages that will be part of the gradle output.

The usual System.out.println(...) and log.debug(...) do not work. How can one set this up?

Comment: Why exactly do you have such an exotic use case ?

Comment: Also how will you run the tests ? And gradle output where ? To the CLI or into JUnit ?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356543/logging-while-testing-through-gradle/35457740)?

Comment: If you look into the setup in this [article](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-running-unit-tests-with-gradle/) you can see you can log to gradle output via System.out.println()

Comment: @MichałKrzywański Yes!  That's the flag I'm looking for, thank you!